# How do I set a top level variable in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a script file, like so:

```
foo = 1

def bar():
    return foo

# The Main function for this script.
def main(argv=None):
    foo = 2
    print bar()
    return
```

This prints 1.
Is there any way to set the value of foo at the script-level from main?

Answer (score 8):

```
foo = 1

def bar():
    return foo

# The Main function for this script.
def main(argv=None):
    global foo
    foo = 2
    print bar()
    return
```

This is in the python documentation.

Answer (score 6):

```
def main(argv=None):
    global foo
    foo = 2
    print bar()
    return
```